# sql sum repeats from sql query?

Tags: sql

I have a sql output which shows the sales_id and the car manufacturers(car_info) they have sold.

I want to create an extra column in the output which shows a total of the manufacturers sold instead as it shows currently just the sales_id and repeats manufacturers associated to each sale

The query I am currently using is :

```
SELECT i.car_info 
  FROM inventory i 
  JOIN sales s ON s.car_id = i.car_id
WHERE s.sales_id = 'sales_id1';
```

I have attempted to use the  sum and the count function but have had no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT i.car_info ,count(1)
  FROM inventory i 
  JOIN sales s ON s.car_id = i.car_id
WHERE s.sales_id = 'sales_id1'
group by i.car_info
```

Comment: thanks it works Ahmad will accept in 5 minutes (SOF protocol)

Answer (score 2):

you need to `GROUP BY` on car manufacturer

```
select i.car_manu, count(s.sales_d)
from inventory i join sales s on s.car_id = i.car_id
where s.sales_id = 'sales_id1'
group by i.car_manu
```